# BigQuery burst rows based on start/end date overlap

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following data

| id | percent | start_date | end_date | priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 59269 | 0 | 2022-01-01 | 2099-12-31 | 2 |
| 59269 | 0.25 | 2023-07-02 | 2023-07-03 | 1 |

I want to be able to query it to ultimately get the following output

| id | percent | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 59269 | 0 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-07-01 |
| 59269 | 0.25 | 2023-07-02 | 2023-07-03 |
| 59269 | 0 | 2023-07-04 | 2099-12-31 |

This ensures the start/end dates don't have an overlap and effectively slots the second row in.

I've played a little with CTE's, but haven't been able to set anything up in a way that accomplishes the outcome stated above.

Comment: How do columns `percent` and `priority` relate to each other? Does the solution need to use both, or just percent?

Comment: @Isolated `percent` is the one that really matters. for a given `id` and date range, its the thing that is changing that matters. I actually just added `priority` to visually show which row should take priority given 7/2/2023 -> 7/3/2023 falls between 1/1/2022 -> 12/31/2099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the need to use windows function - as shown next - to solve this or several joins. CTE are helping. The CTE table `tbl` is the given example. For testing, change `1=1` to `1=2` to set the final date to null.

The CTE `time_tbl`gives of each id the list of all starts and ends dates in one column `dates`. Please query this CTE first to understand the following. This CTE unions all starts and end dates for each id. This is done by the `unnest` of the array of both dates. Please note that a null end date will be masked as the date 3000-11-11.

The given date ranges are inclusive, the values should also apply for the start and end date. For the splitting of the time intervals, we need to substract one day from the start date and add a day to the end date.

The window function `window1` and `lead` is used to obtain the next entry of the `dates` column. Also the `final_date` for each id is calculated by the `max`imum of the `dates` column. The `qualify` removes the last row for each id.

The main select joins the CTE `time_tbl` with the data `tbl` which fits the id and the time range. If several time criterial are fulfilled, the maximum of the `percentage` is taken. Please see also the comment out lines. In case there are many entries for an id, this join will be not performant. A better solution could be archived by using here a window function as well. In cases this applies for you, please provide more information about your data amount and a bigger data example.

```sql
With tbl as 
(SELECT
59269 as id,    0 percent,   if(1=1,date    "2022-01-01" ,null) as start_date, if(1=1,date    "2099-12-31" ,null)as end_date, 2 as priority
union all select 59269, 0.20,   date "2023-07-02", date "2023-07-03",   1
#union all select 59269, 0.25,   date "2023-07-03", date "2023-07-14",   1 # start date is equal to last end date - this is not possible - duplicate rows
#union all select 59269, 0.30,   date "2023-07-15", date "2023-07-17",   1 # this will work fine
),
time_tbl as (
SELECT distinct A.id, dates, lead(dates) over window1 as date_end, 
max(dates) over window1 as final_date, #last date for the id
from tbl A,unnest([start_Date-1,ifnull(end_date+1,date "3000-11-11")]) as dates # start dates affect the previos day and end_day the next day
qualify date_end is not null
window window1 as (partition by A.id order by dates)
),
tbl2 as
(
Select A.id,
 greatest(ifnull(max(B.start_date),A.dates),A.dates) as start_date,
 case when min(B.end_date) is null and A.date_end!= date "3000-11-11"  then A.date_end
 else 
 least(min(B.end_date),A.date_end)
 end as end_date,
#count(1) as info,
max(percent) percent,
#array_agg(percent) percent_array
from time_tbl A
left join tbl B
on A.id=B.id and (B.start_date is null or B.start_date-1<=A.dates  and A.date_end <= B.end_date+1 or B.end_date is null)
group by A.id,A.dates,A.date_end

)

Select *,
date_diff(end_date,start_date,day) as duration
from tbl2
qualify duration=max(duration) over (partition by id,start_date)
order by 1,2
```

The query is not capable of cleaning up time intervals. When the start and end date of any records match, there will be additional rows in the output.

Comment: That is some voodoo magic right there :p -- thanks so much, now to read-up on: unnest, qualify & window!

Comment: found a small issue, looks like that query returns:
59269 / 2023-07-02 / 2023-07-02 / 0.25
as the middle row, where it should be:
59269 / 2023-07-02 / 2023-07-03 / 0.25

Comment: @DavidCummings Thanks for pointing this out. I updated my answer. The given time intervals should include the start date and the end date. For splitting there is the need to do some adding and subtracting